# Ionic app looks small in high res devices

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm new on ionic. I'm building a simple demo app to decide if I will use ionic or not in my project.

I'm currently having this problem styling the app. Default theme looks OK in low-res devices, but looks too small in high-res devices (look the example images at the bottom)

Is there a way to resolve this globally? I want to AVOID creating custom meadia queries per resolution.

[Screen capture of 480x800px device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEnUB.png)

[image]

[Screen capture of 768x1280px device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk41X.png)

[image: Screen capture of 768x1280px device]

Comment: post your layout code..

Comment: Show something from your code?

Comment: @Muhsin what do you want to check? is basically ionic starter project "sidemenu". I see that all units (font sizes, heights, etc) are in px in ionic css, so a general solution like increasing body font-size is not possible. I don't know if I'm missing something or if this is a general limitation. There isn't a way to convert 'px' to "dp" units or something like that?

Comment: @CodeProcessor:Did you try media queries?